# Add disk to software raid pool

Tags: raid, lvm

I have a setup like this there run a mirroring software raid1 but its possible to add a disk more and use its like a raid5 or how do i add more storage to the raid?

**Current with 2 disks**

```
| / | /var | /usr | /home  |
 --------------------------
|       LVM Volume         |
 --------------------------
|       RAID Volume        |
 --------------------------
|    Disk 1  |   Disk 2    |
```

**New with 3 disks**

```
| / | /var | /usr | /home  |
 --------------------------
|       LVM Volume         |
 --------------------------
|       RAID Volume        |
 --------------------------
| Disk 1 | Disk 2 | Disk 3 |
```

Comment: In principle yes, see https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/A_guide_to_mdadm#.22Grow.22ing_non-parity_raid_arrays. The same page has a paragraph on adding a disk to a mirror.

Comment: In addition, I strongly suggest to do full array health check before any modifications. It'll be very hard to fix if something fails during the migration process. At least do built-in check https://lxadm.com/Mdadm:_stopping_and_starting_RAID_check_in_Linux and check SMART status to see if there are any signs of problems.

Comment: You should have regular checks anyway. Just last week, I had a bad disk in a RAID5, but since it was found during a check and not during recovery, that wasn't a big deal.